# Can human hair feasibly replace down as clothing filling?

Tags: clothing, upcycling

I came across [this](https://www.trendwatching.com/innovation-of-the-day/human-material-loop-tests-prototype-parka-filled-with-human-hair?utm_campaign=FTU%20Weekly%20&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=241278558&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--Q-sdbXJhocKsE-JoTxEkpaVaotYzKilMmaooz-rNvjSEMa31iJeB1DivME2JykDlG3iXJtxCNXMUA9cnpstwXhlHTcw&utm_content=241275125&utm_source=hs_email) news about a parka prototype that uses human hair as an alternative for animal hair, that is down or wool. Using human hair seems an obvious idea so the fact that it's not practiced by manufacturers makes me suspect that it's not a good replacer (whatever the reasons). In other words, they would've done it already had it possessed necessary properties. Can human hair replace down after all?

Comment: Whether it's feasible or not, there are [ethical issues with selling human hair](https://borgenproject.org/ethics-of-human-hair-trade/#:~:text=increase%20farmers%27%20earnings.-,The%20ethics%20of%20human%20hair%20trade%20can%20be%20complex.,consent%20and%20are%20paid%20fairly.).

Comment: @LShaver by the same token, aren't there ethical issues with exploiting animals?

Comment: It is not down. More like a replacement for horse hair.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, [Vegetarian.SE] might have a community to answer this question (I think replacing animal hair by human hair would make it vegan if no humans are coerced to part with their hair).

Comment: Physically feasible yes. However human hair requires significant quantity if donors. Also widely bought for hair extensions. Wigs. Etc.

Comment: Due to incidents of 20th century history, this idea would not be received well at all here in Germany.

Comment: @LazyReader mine (and many other men's) hair wouldn't be much use for wigs - what's cut off is too short.  The grey ones probably aren't worth much either.  So it would be quite available for this, if hair was useful

Comment: A lot of hair is goes in the rubbish bin of barber shops and hairdressers around the world. It would be poor quality, but it could be used for cheap canvas and there would be a lot of applications for it. It does not necessarily have to be used to replace down or wool. If the media does not make the usual fuss out of it I don't think that the ethical issues could be such a problem. Collecting the rubbish of a barber shop would not be such a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, what keeps us from getting cold in winter clothing is air. Air is a bad conductor of heat and any structure that has loads of air pockets will keep you warm. Down (as well as other types of feather) has that kind of property due to its microscopically branched structure. On top, it is very light weight.

Human hair does not fullfill that brief. If you felt it (think dreadlocks), you might be able to get better warmth retention due to the air pockets you create, but you will end up with a very heavy material, similar to boiled wool. It will be stiff and thick and not very comfortable.

And last but not least: down is very compressible, making it suitable for items like sleeping bags that you do not want to have to carry around in their full bulk. Human hair in a form that retains warmth (see previous paragraph) will not be compressible.

So while technically you could use human hair to replace down in various scenarios, the resulting product properties will be completely different (and in most instances very much inferior). A much better candidate to replace down if you do not want to use animal products is e.g. [poplar seed fiber](https://www.pappella.de/pappelflaum/pappelflaum.php) (link only in German), which has the highest warmth retention capacity of any natural fiber, is very lightweight and not spinnable, making it unattractive to regular textile production methods, which is why it is not widely used yet.